# Require Id of html tag in app.js from ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

sort.ejs file code

```
<html>
<form action="/" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="bubble" value="bubble">Bubble Sort</button>
</form>

<hr id = "123" style="height:<%=hgt%>px;border-left: <%=width%>px solid black;float: left;margin-left:<%=margin%>px">

</html>
```

app.js file code

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("sort",{array:array,size:200,flag1:0,flag2:0,flag3:0,flag4:0});
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){


}
```

I want to print the value of style elements(height, margin) of the hr tag in sort.ejs file in my terminal when the post request gets triggered. All the variables used in sort.ejs are predefined.
I am using Node.js and EJS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit confused about your Query. but if you're asking about how to get value from app.js and set in sort.ejs then you should use <%- %> tag instead of <%= %>.

so your look like below:

```
<hr id = "123" style="height:<%- hgt %>px;border-left: <%- width %>px solid black;float: left;margin-left:<%- margin %>px">
```

Here are some basic info about different tags in ejs.

**<%=** Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)

**<%-** Outputs the unescaped value into the template

For more details you can refer this link: [EJS Reference](https://ejs.co/)

Comment: I want to get the style values of the hr tag using body-parser or any other tool in the app.js file. Actually I am having a for loop in sort.ejs file and have given unique id to all hr tag and all the style values(height,border-left) of each hr tag is also unique defined in the for loop and I want to store the values of its style in an array which is in app.js file.